# how to use environment variable in spring boot properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sqlite, properties

i have an app with spring boot that i want to connect to sqlite database in that path C:\Users\user7\AppData\Roaming.
what i have to write on the app.properties to indicate environment variable APPDATA path?
this is my app.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:sqlite:sqlitesample.db
```

how to use APPDATA variable?
regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the solution

```
spring.datasource.url =jdbc:sqlite:${APPDATA}/sqlitesample.db
```